# What is the "defaults write" command to highlight bad layout?

Tags: ios, macos, autolayout

There is a system preference that can be turned on to debug layouts on OS X.  It draws a rounded rect around a window with about 50px of padding and a magenta background.  I believe it does this when the layout contains elements that are hidden by other elements or not laid out properly. Does anyone know what I'm referring to, and what the preference is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints.